# Could not solve following optimization problem

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I am completely new to optimization. I only know one method of optimization, i.e. optimization using the differentiation (without any constraint).

I am trying to find the optimal value of $x$. Note the following. $a \in \{1,1/4, 1/2, 3/4\}$ and $n$ is an integer such that $ 50 \leq n \leq 500$. $b$ is also an integer and $5\leq b \leq 44$

\begin{align}
f(x) = a\left(1-\dfrac{a}{x}\right)\left(1-\dfrac{a}{bx}\right)^{n-2}
\end{align}

\begin{align}
f'(x) = \dfrac{a^2\left(1-\frac{a}{bx}\right)^{n-2}}{x^2}+\dfrac{a^2\left(n-2\right)\left(1-\frac{a}{x}\right)\left(1-\frac{a}{bx}\right)^{n-3}}{bx^2}
\end{align}

letting $ f'(x) = 0$, we get

\begin{equation}
x = \dfrac{a(n-1)}{n+b-2}  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \  (1)
\end{equation}

Now $x $ is itself an integer and should be $5\leq x \leq 64$. But the roots of $x$ as shown in (1) does not give me the correct result.

How can I proceed?

PS. Example. If $a = 1/2, n = 100, b = 10$, then $x < 1$ and

Comment: do you want a min or max of your function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

plugging your solution $$x=\frac{a(n-1)}{b+n-2}$$ in the second derivative so i get a Minimum for your $x$ since the second derivative is positive $${\frac { \left( -2+b+n \right) ^{4}}{a \left( n-2 \right)  \left( b-1
 \right)  \left( n-1 \right) ^{2}} \left( {\frac { \left( n-2 \right) 
 \left( b-1 \right) }{b \left( n-1 \right) }} \right) ^{n-2}}
$$

Comment: So it means it does not have any maxima? What about if I use the constraints above. How can I know if an equation does not have the maxima?

Comment: i have told you already i have used the second derivative test, i think there is no Maximum, also if we use the constraints above

Comment: you can also use a plot of your function using the constraints above